# error: option --reload not recognized

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/workspace/abc$ pserve --reload development.ini 
Starting subprocess with file monitor
at start of server
usage: pserve [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: pserve --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: pserve --help-commands
   or: pserve cmd --help

error: option --reload not recognized
```

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move reload behind ini file like :

```
../bin/pserve development.ini --reload
```

Probably as the first argument it needs pyramid config file